# Won't add navigation item to navigation bar in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigation

I'm trying to create a back button on my navigation bar in x code. However when I drag it across from the objects library to the navigation bar in the storyboard it doesn't come up.

Comment: I've noticed some strange behavior.  Its as if the back button is hidden behind the bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the navigation is not set up correctly, as dbajkovic mentioned, if you do not have a navigationcontroller, it will not work.  Your scoreboard should look like this:

[image: Navigaation Setup]

You can not add the button to the left, only to the right.

Comment: I tried doing what you did. I set up a navigation controller but when I drag it into the bar it doesn't come up as a button as a whole new bar. I have found a way around it though, I can just use a bar button item instead the only difference is that it doesn't have a point

Comment: is the navigation push? (not modal.)

Answer (score 3):

OK So this is crazy but...

Click on the navigation bar and in the attributes inspector, Just Type something in the field marked Back Button.  Then in the scene hierarchy you'll see the button, though it won't yet appear on your navbar. In the hierarchy, drag the button onto the Navigation Item and viola it appears.  Now to make second one, hold option and copy the first one. If you try to add one from the object browser, you'll lose the first one.

If done properly, the first will show up on the right and the second on the left.

Good luck.

Comment: I've created a new view controller, then I added a navigation bar and all I want to do is drag in a navigation item but it doesn't work. I don't really want to work with a new navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Thompson: I came across your post and since I just learnt something new, I am going to add it as a response to your question.

There are two separate buttons - Back button and Bar Button. Back button has a reverse (right to left) pointing arrow and a Bar button is a regular rectangular button. The following describes how your could implement them in your program:

1. Back button:
   On the root view controller, ctrl + click on button and drag it to the view controller you are trying to connect it to. When you are given an option to select from, choose `Push`, not `modal`. This will automatically add a back button on the next view controller. (Run the program to confirm it.)
2. Bar Button: (Credit: dbrajkovic)
   For adding the bar button, click on navigation bar of the navigationViewController you are interested in. Under `Attributes inspector`, type some name in `Back Button` and hit enter to confirm. Open `document outline` and locate the viewController you were working on. On the left side of `Navigation Item` locate the disclosure triangle. Click on the `Bar Button Item`. Ctrl + click + drag the button to the navigation bar of that viewController. You can choose whether to place it on the left / right side.